# Uncaught Error : cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

I don't know why it cannot find module. I think **loader** in webpack.config.js is wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

---

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/Images"
    at webpackMissingModule (app.js:3)
    at Object._hyphenPattern (app.js:3)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 8f180ae…:19)
    at module.exports (bootstrap 8f180ae…:65)
    at bootstrap 8f180ae…:65

---

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'build/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'build/bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
               }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

./src/components/Images.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Images extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Images Component
            </div>
       )
    }
}

export default Images
```

./src/app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Images from './components/Images'

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                This is the react App!
                more stuff!!
                <Images />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: For your `entry` field in your webpack config, try `__dirname + "/src/app.js"`.  Alternatively, since every node project should have an index.js, try setting your entry point to `__dirname + "/index.js"`, then have index.js pull in src/app.js.

Comment: `entry: {
        app: __dirname+'/src/app.js'
    }`

I changed `entry` like this but it still have an **Error in ./src/app.js**

Comment: This might be a longshot but have you tried (../) instead of (./): `import Images from '../components/Images'`

Comment: No.. it doesn't work T_T